# Swift - accessing nil does not crash

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa, null

I noticed a strange behavior in swift.
The following code will print "Not found" as one would expect.

```
import Cocoa

var array = [["one":"1"]]

for element in array {
    if let check = element["two"] {
        print(check)
    } else {
        print("Not found")
    }
}
```

Slightly changing the code to

```
import Cocoa

var array : [AnyObject]?
array = [["one":"1"]]

for element in array! {  
    if let check = element["two"] {
        print(check)
    } else {
        print("Not found")
    } 
}
```

will print "nil" - that's not what I was expecting as I thought in swift a nil is a "not set" and not a printable object.

Is there something i'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Not clear why it would be `nil` at all since the only point at which the array is `nil` is when it's declared as an optional Type but not initialized. You then set a value for `array` immediately, which is before either unwrapping or checking its contents. I'd expect it to say "Not found" for the 2nd case as well. Perhaps I'm not clear on distinction between `[AnyObject?]` and `[AnyObject]?`

Comment: I'd expect element["two"] to be nil which should cause "check" to be nil but "print(check)" actually prints "nil"

Comment: I'm actually surprised the compiler lets you subscript an `AnyObject` in the first place... in my opinion you shouldn't be allowed to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, you're actually creating a nested optional, which is generally not a good idea (it only leads to confusion, and I don't know why the compiler allows it frankly).  If you put in the line:

```
let foo = element["two"]
```

and inspect `foo`'s type, you'll see that it is `AnyObject?!`.  So it's an optional with no value wrapped in an optional.  This has the effect of making your `if/let` statement unwrap the first optional to give you a second optional, which is `nil`.